# Error pasting data into a TextInput

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

In my Flex 4 application I have a spark text input. When the user pastes data from clipBoard it throws error if the clipBoard contains a different format (other than string). This is the error message i am getting.

```
"TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at spark.components::RichEditableText/handlePasteOperation()
[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\RichEditableText.as:3611]"
```

Is there any way to handle this?

Thanks
Manoj

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is [a](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/779122) [known](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2904634) [problem](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2030606). The only suggestion I could find was from *rdermer* on one of those threads:

> If you have a local copy of TLF 1.1
>   you can work around it by adding a
>   test at line 346 of TextClipboard.as. 
>   Replace
>        endArray.push(curFlElement); with
>       if (curFlElement)
>           endArray.push(curFlElement);   That prevents the bug - but the
>   underlying cause needs more
>   investigation.